# Node.js Cookies not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm hosting a node.js file on my website, and I'm trying to get data through cookies.
I am using editmycookie, and I can see that the cookies ARE set.

I have a function that gets the cookies from a name

```
function parseCookies(request, finding){
   rc = request.headers.cookie + ';';
   rc && rc.split(';').forEach(function( cookie ) {
      var parts = cookie.split('=');
      if(parts.shift().trim() == finding){
          return decodeURI(parts.join('=')).replace(/-/g, '=');
      }

   });
}
```

Then I run this, knowing the cookies are set

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
   user = parseCookies(req, 'user');
   pass = parseCookies(req, 'pass');
   console.log(user + pass);
```

and it logs as NaN

I'm still learning Node, sorry.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 if that helps!\

Weirdly enough, it works for some users on my site, and for some it doesn't.  I haven't noticed a pattern of whose work and whose do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the cookies using this code and lets see how it works

```
    var http = require('http');
    function parseCookies (request) {
    var list = {},
    rc = request.headers.cookie;
    rc && rc.split(';').forEach(function( cookie ) {
    var parts = cookie.split('=');
    list[parts.shift().trim()] = decodeURI(parts.join('='));
    });
    return list;
   }
   http.createServer(function (request, response) {

  // To Read a Cookie
  var cookies = parseCookies(request);

  // To Write a Cookie
  response.writeHead(200, {
    'Set-Cookie': 'mycookie=test',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  });
  response.end('Hello World\n');
  }).listen(8124);

  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

And add your routes to which you want to call.Hope this hepls for you.

Answer (score 2):

You do not return anything from the `parseCookies` function, the `return decodeURI(parts.join('=')).replace(/-/g, '=')` is called with the callback of the foreach, so this return is *meaningless*.

Because for that `parseCookies` returns `undefined` and `undefined + undefined` is `NaN`.

When using `forEach` you need to save the matched result in an temporary variable `result`, and return this one.

```
function parseCookies(request, finding) {
  var result;
  var rc = request.headers.cookie + ';';
  rc && rc.split(';').forEach(function(cookie) {
    var parts = cookie.split('=');
    if (parts.shift().trim() == finding) {
      result = decodeURI(parts.join('=')).replace(/-/g, '=');
    }
  });

  return result;
}
```

Or use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (I didn't have time to test that version so there might be a bug in it):

```
function parseCookies(request, finding) {
  var rc = request.headers.cookie + ';';

  var cookie = rc.split(';').find(cookie => cookie.split('=').shift().trim() == finding);

  return decodeURI(cookie.split('=').join('=')).replace(/-/g, '=');
}
```

But why do you parse the cookies your self anyway. There are robust and well tested middlewares that will do this for you.